# In-place for loop to in-place list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, in-place

I want to know if there is a way to do the code above as an in-place list comprehension or using a `map()` (just the for loop):

```
s = [''] * n
s[0:k] = ['X'] * k
for i in range(k,m): 
    s[i] = foo(s[i-k:i])
```

If I do:

```
s = [''] * n
s[0:k] = ['X'] * k
s = [foo(s[i-k:i]) for i in range(k,m)]
```

the `s` will not be updated correctly.

Comment: It's already incomprehensible enough

Comment: you realize `i-k` will have negative values in the beginning since `k > 0` and `i >= 0`, what will cause the indices `[i-k:i]` to have no meaning (empty list)

Comment: @UrielEli Sorry, I edited

Comment: I think list comprehensions and `map()` both return new lists, so neither are what you would want to do for in-place modification of your existing list.

Comment: Comprehensions are functional constructs. They always return a new data-structure. You can update your own with that new one, but that muddies the water. Stick to imperative constructs (loops with append) if you are going to be mutating a data structure, stick with functional constructs if you are going to be programming in the functional style.

Comment: You can simplify the initialization with `s = ['X' if i < k else '' for i in range(n)]`, but I don't see a way to lose the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The killer case here is that if m > 2*k, we get **foo** taking as input something it produced as output on a prior call.  That means that we can't simply evaluate **s** statically and iterate blithely over the known elements -- the elements after s[max(k, n)] are unknown at the initial evaluation, so feeding one of those to **foo** is a dynamic quantity.

Imagine that **foo** returns something dependent on the initial value and something random; it's easy enough to see that the propagation from one part of the list to another doesn't work statically.  For instance, have **foo** append a random hex digit, and let's try both ideas in the original posting:

```
import random
def foo(chr_list):
    inventory = "0123456789abcdef"
    return chr_list[0] + random.choice(inventory)

k = 3
m = 10
n = 16
s = [''] * n
s[0:k] = ['X'] * k

print "1 s init", s 
for i in range(k,m): 
    s[i] = foo(s[i-k:i])
print "1 s done", s
print

s = [''] * n
s[0:k] = ['X'] * k
print "2 s init", s
s = [foo(s[i-k:i]) for i in range(k,m)]
print "2 s done", s
```

Output:

```
1 s init ['X', 'X', 'X', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
1 s done ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X7', 'Xd', 'X9', 'X74', 'Xd6', 'X9d', 'X741', '', '', '', '', '', '']

2 s init ['X', 'X', 'X', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
2 s done ['X8', 'X2', 'X9', 'f', 'd', '0', '7']
```

In summary, I don't think it's *worth* putting this into a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention, list comprehension always create a new list. Your original list s will be gone if you directly assign result of list comprehension into it.

You can replace slice of original list with the result of list comprehension as below

```
# compact initialization into 1 line
s = ['X']*k + [''] * (n-k)
# replace slice of list s from k to m
s[k:m] = [foo(s[i-k:i]) for i in range(k,m)]
```